# What happens to TFS 2015 reporting Server when you detach and then reattch a project collection?

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, tfs-2015, detach

I needed to detach a project collection from our production server so I could back it up and restore it to our test server. The collection is used for Training.

After the backup I reattached the collection back into the Production server. I was able to verify that I could navigate the project in the TFS web UI. I went to check the report server and all the team/project folders are there, but all the folders are empty.

I was able to open excel and connect to the Analysis cube, but when I open the collection for examine test plans results, I see the following:

```
{Deleted} DD1_MVH_AutoReg (A0302C3A-813E-499A-9D60-DE912D8DA610)
{Deleted} EDI_TIBCO (6A4FE9BB-82BB-44DB-81BE-0EFC7227D061)
{Deleted} EITQA Testing Area (D865EED5-F0B7-4F04-930E-1EE71358C204)
{Deleted} EITQA-CMMI (DEAA03FB-A5E0-4FF4-979B-A87D29810A68)
{Deleted} EITQA-Heather (4E4C75A6-0502-4B56-B52F-FA03CEB8FBE7)
{Deleted} EITQA-Pat (CF53C3A8-FF9E-44AE-AC9B-DB71B3E530BC)
{Deleted} HI EOB Team (D7CF3151-4665-4089-9CE0-5684C785BC31)
```

Do I have to wait for the Cube to rebuild, and do I need to "Push" the reports back into the reporting server?

Answer (score 1):

When you do attach the collection option, **if the deployment you're moving to uses reporting, a reporting folder and default reports will be built** for the collection you're attaching as part of the process.

If you want to move the reports with collection, take a look at this tutorial:  **[My TFS deployment uses reporting. How do I move reports along with moving a collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/move-project-collection#q-my-tfs-deployment-uses-reporting-how-do-i-move-reports-along-with-moving-a-collection)**

In your case, you could first give a test with  Rebuild the data warehouse and Analysis Services:

1. Open the administration console for Team Foundation.
2. In the navigation bar, choose **Reporting**.
3. In Reporting, choose **Start Rebuild**.
4. In the Rebuild the Warehouse and Analysis Services Databases dialog
   box, choose OK.

If this not work, the reports still be empty, you may have to manually move reports, detail steps just follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/move-project-collection#to-move-reports).